# Proof correct? Expectation and O-notation

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable and $p > 1$. I want to prove that
$$ E ( X^p) < \infty \Longrightarrow E (f(X)^p) < \infty,$$
if $f(x) = O(x)$. This statement makes absolut sense and my proof goes as follows. Let $M, x_0$ be such that $$ f(x) \leq M \, x \quad \forall x \geq x_0.$$
Then, $$ E (f(X)^p) = E ( \mathbb{1}_{X \leq x_0} f(X)^p) + E (\mathbb{1}_{X > x_0} f(X)^p) \leq f(x_0)^p + E (\mathbb{1}_{X > x} M^p X^p) \leq f(x_0)^p + M^p E(X^p) < \infty.$$

Is this correct, and is there an even easier way to show this (or is the above statement even trivial)?

Comment: An $M^p$ is missing in front of $E[X^p]$ in the end. You also don't mention that $f$ should be monotone, so I don't see how you can upper bound the expected value of $f$ below $x_0$ by $f(x_0)$. I wonder if you can upper bound it at all as the big O notation intentionally not says what happens for small values of $x$...

Comment: @NeitherNor Oh ok, so the statement is probably only true for monotone $f$ then. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about this... the question is if the details in the definition of big-O allow us to construct an $f$ which diverges for values of $x$ smaller than $x_0$ or not. Never thought about this...

Comment: Ok, Kavi's answer says that big-O is actually allowing it. Guessed so but couldn't believe how stupid that is. Anyway, so what you probably want is that $f$ is $O(x)$ both for $x\rightarrow\infty$ and $x\rightarrow-\infty$, and that $f$ is additionally locally bonded. Not sure if this suffices...but I kind of also remember that there is some relationship between E(f(X)) and f(E(X)) under certain conditions

Comment: Yes, here we go: if $f$ is convex, all you probably need is Jensen's inequality: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Comment: @NeitherNor Thank you very much. Still, if $f$ is increasing my proof would be correct, right? So even for non-convex functions, the statement can hold?

Answer (score 2):

This is not even true. Let $f(x)=\frac 1  x$ for $x >0$ and $0$ for $x \leq 0$. Then the hypothesis holds with $x_0=1$ and $M=1$. Take $p=2$ for example. Can you think of an example where $X > 0, EX^{2} <\infty$ but $E\frac 1 {X^{2}}=\infty$?

Comment: I could only think of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Then, $ E \frac{1}{X^2} = \infty$. Is this such an example (even though $X> 0$ only almost surely)?

Comment: @MATH101 Sets of measure $0$ don't matter. Define $Y$ to be $X$ when $X >0$ and $1$ when $X =0$.